# Bower package manager in visual studio not showing all packages

Tags: visual-studio-2015

This is the second time that I have had to install a package with e.g.

```
bower install literallycanvas
```

After not being able to find it in the 'Manage Bower packages' GUI in vs2015 (Latest RC)

Why would it fail to appear in the 'Browse' tab, yet be available to install from the command line?

Comment: Are the missing packages you mention prerelease versions? There's a **Include prerelease** tick box in the bower gui that is unticked by default  that may be omitting some results.

Answer (score 0):

I've often had Visual studio not include new libraries installed through bower - in your solution manager on the right of the IDE, click the button that says "show all files" (it looks like a bunch of pages) and look under bower_components, and see if it's there. If it's an outline of the file, right click and click include in project.

If not, look in the bower.json file to make sure that it's listed. I'm fairly confident it must also be specified in your BundleConfig.cs file under the App_Start folder

Comment: I didnt mean that... If you have the latest RC of VS2015 you will see they have added a Bower package manager GUI, the package is not appearing in there.